# How to use the internal HDD in a SSD+HDD laptop?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-disk, ssd, laptop

My Dell Vostro 3491 came with 1TB HDD and 256 SSD. Ubuntu was installed on the SSD and I can use the drive for storing and accessing files. But I am unable to access the HDD.

From the disk utilities, it seems my HDD is on standby (displaying ZZZ).

Using `sudo fdisk -l` I found my HDD is marked as `/dev/sda` and no partitions.

I tried mounting it using `sudo /mount /dev/sda /media/HDD` but getting an error `mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.`

What is the actual problem and how to solve it?

Do I need to create partition of /dev/sda ? Why?

Comment: Do you want to know how to `mount` a drive, where to find it in `/dev` and/or how to format it beforehand?

Comment: Have you tried creating and formatting partitions within `/dev/sda` (with GNOME Disk or GPartEd) before trying to mount them ?

Answer (score 1):

Sorted this out. I had to format the HDD and then mount it as:

```
sudo mkdir /media/HDD
sudo mount /dev/sda /media/HDD
```

Comment: NO, you want partitions like sda1, not a drive like sda. You may not be able to remount as almost all tools expect partitions. and you want gpt partitions, not 35 year old MBR(msdos) partitions. You can also use gparted but must change default partitioning first.
Select gpt under device, advanced over msdos(MBR) default partitioning before starting. gparted & fdisk instructions:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingANewHardDrive & 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition/OperatingSystemsAndPartitions

Comment: The command `sudo lshw -C disk` does not show up anything!